# Overwrite "ext" field in gradle library

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using an open source library which has an "ext" block in its gradle  defining some variables, like:

```
ext {
   MIN_SDK = 14
   TARGET_SDK = 25
   BUILD_TOOLS = '25.0.2'
}
```

If in my project I want to use another version of the build_tools, I receive the error for "mixing versions".
I would like to define a "global" BUILD_TOOLS parameter overriding all the ones defined into libraries.
I tried something like:

```
project.ext {
  BUILD_TOOLS = '25.3.1'
}
```

in my project gradle, but it seems not to work.
Is there a way to do that without changing all the libraries gradle codes?

Comment: Add your versions in the ext block of the library since you have write access on it

Comment: Can you explain better? Because it seems exactly what I want to avoid, modify the library code. I just want to import it as it is, using gradle "compile" command.

Comment: try to change the name of your variable in your project "APP_BUILD_TOOLS" for example